# How to solve updating a list of contacts depending on user input, 429 error (too many requests)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, architecture

We have a react frontend, that has a name field, a user will write in the field and a list with search results of their contacts shows up, each time the user writes a character the search is updated. Right now it sends a request with a search query to the server each time a new letter is added in the field and this creates a whole bun ch of requests.

How would you solve this? send the whole list and the let the client to the search? I would prefer not to. Maybe limit the requests in some way? I assume this must be something that every search engine has to handle some way?

Comment: Send request to search user only if the input have 3 or x characters. This will avoid having results for a single letter.

Comment: Also add debouncing: wait about 300-500ms before sending the request, if input value didn't change, then proceed with the request, otherwise abort it and wait another 300-500ms. This makes somewhat sure that user finished typing before sending the request